# How can I refresh a ng-repeat after drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm developing a page in AngularJs that require a folder-tree. This folder-tree is made with an ng-repeat that iterate over an array of element.
Today I started developing the drag and drop functionality to drag a file inside a folder. I used [Sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) for the drag and drop functionality but, since I didn't want to reorder the tree but to drop INSIDE the element I encapsulated the row in another div that only contain that row so that when I drag inside that give I can trick the user to think that I'm dropping IN the folder.

So the structure is basically this

```html
<div class="node-dnd-container" ng-repeat="node in nodes">
  <div class="node">
    <!-- folder/file title, icon..... --->
  </div>
</div>
```

After I detect that the drop took place I do some magic stuff to change the parent structure and with that all the children that were inside and I refresh the model connected to the ng-repeat.

The funny thing that now happens is that the ng-repeat module is refreshed but no I have in the html a node-dnd-container with two nodes inside (because of the drag & drop). So basically the ng-repeat refreshed correctly but not in the right order having something inside the ng-repeat that shouldn't be there.

I can fix this problem using angular.copy and deep-copy the model but then is detached from the controller and if I change something in the controller is not reflected in the view.

TL-DR: How can you refresh completely an ng-repeat (refreshing the hashes also) without deep-coping (detaching so the view from the controller)

Comment: Looks like you are using plugin which is manupulating DOM using jQuery..which doen't understand by angular..So you need to tell angular to run digest cycle to see the changes..

Comment: But Sortable has also an Angular implementation. You are telling me to do a $scope.$apply ?

Comment: If you are using jQuery version then yes..You have not mentioned that you are using angular version of it

Comment: I added a $scope.$apply() at the end and it didn't change anything. I think that angular keeps some record saying: "This didn't changed so no need to refresh" but instead I need to refresh it. That's why the deep copy works

Comment: This is where you should be taking advantage of 2-way data binding. Assuming your managing your nodes list correctly. Can you show your controller of how you are managing nodes (add/remove) ?